# How can I prevent ExtJS 4.2.1 from processing the totalProperty on a PUT request?

Tags: exception, extjs4, put

We are using `ExtJS 4.2.1` and `Spring MVC / Data-Rest`.  Anyway, the data-rest will return the following structure on a successful `GET` request:

```
{
    content: [ ... objects .... ],
    links: [ ... list of rel links ... ],
    page: {
        size: 25,
        totalElements: 4,
        totalPages: 1,
        number: 1
    }
}
```

So, in my proxies, I have set the `totalProperty` to `page.totalElements`.   Works great.

However, when we send a `PUT` request, the natural (and correct, I believe) response is to send a `204 NO CONTENT`.  Now, if our `totalProperty` were set to something like `total` (not `page.xxx`) then it's fine.  But ExtJS is trying to parse the `page.totalElements` and returning an exception because `page` is null.

So how can I tell ExtJS to ignore the totalProperty on a PUT request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha.  Looks like I found a work-around.  Not sure if I like it but it works.  I changed my controller as such:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
```

Where as before, it was:

```
return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
```

ExtJS seems to not mind that.  Strange.

Answer (score 0):

@cbmeeks, I had a similar issue in Ext.JS **4.1.3**, and I posted the fix [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127585-FIXED-EXTJSIV-224-http-204-%28No-Content%29-return-error).

```js
/**  
 * Fix for Json reader when the HTTP response is Status Code: 204 No Content and  
 * at least one of the pair root/totalProperty is not a direct property of the returned json  
 * http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127585  
 * @author rgralhoz  
 */  
Ext.data.reader.Json.override({
    createAccessor: (function () {
        var re = /[\[\.]/;

        return function (expr) {
            if (Ext.isEmpty(expr)) {
                return Ext.emptyFn;
            }
            if (Ext.isFunction(expr)) {
                return expr;
            }
            if (this.useSimpleAccessors !== true) {
                var i = String(expr).search(re);
                if (i >= 0) {
                    return Ext.functionFactory('obj',

                        'return obj' + (i > 0 ?

                            '.hasOwnProperty("' +
                                expr.substring(0, i) +
                                '")? obj.' + expr + ' : null' :

                            expr));
                }
            }
            return function (obj) {
                return obj[expr];
            };
        };
    }())
});
```

**Disclaimer:**

Please add this code to a `fixes.js` file in your project, to override Ext.Js' function. Please notice that:

1. The fix for 4.2.1 may be the same or similar
2. Once you override their function, when you upgrade Ext.Js, make sure they haven't change it, otherwise you'll loose updates on their code.

Comment: Fix for the same issue in Ext.JS 3.1.1:  
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?274536-JsonReader-crashes-when-load-has-no-data-and-root-is-undefined